# Nest Protect Motion Sensor through API?

Tags: nest-api

I'd like to implement some automatic lighting around my house based on presence. Basically, if I get up to go to the kitchen for a glass of water in the middle of the night I'd like a small light to come on to help see. We have Nest Protects and I'd like to tap into the motion sensor on each protect to do this.

I know the Nest Protect has a built in light, but it isn't that bright (thankfully). I can't see anything in the API to do this...which makes me think it isn't possible but I figured it was worth asking.

Comment: Hi. Did you find something about it? Digging on Internet without luck... Thanks.

Comment: No luck. I don't think they have it open to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the Nest Protect doesn't communicate with the servers very often ... even the hard wired Protects only connect once an hour or so.  The battery powered Protects only communicate once a day.

Comment: That's interesting since the protects can be used to determine auto-away...maybe it only communicates with the thermostat often and not outside.

Comment: The protects only provide behavioral information that is used to help calculate the auto-away schedule.